# Counting occurrences based on criterion

Tags: python, csv, pandas, aggregate

I'm trying to count how many total times a color shows up in a dataframe, but I only want it to select them on a selected criteria. 
for example I have:

```
imageName     color1     color2     color3     color4     shape
img1          Red        Red        Red        Red        circle
img2          Blue       Green      Red        Blue       circle
img3          Yellow     Blue       Red        White      square
img4          Blue       Blue       Blue       Blue       circle
```

I want to select all occurrences of 'Red' where shape == circle. 
I've tried groupby but I'm having some trouble conceptually of what I'm supposed to be doing:

```
byShape = df.groupby('shape')...
```

I've tried count() but it shows the total count of each time each shape is listed in every column. Is there something similar to a SQL 'where' in Pandas? I think I may need to do something with aggregate, but I've been unsuccessful using it so far.

EDIT: This is what I get for byShape = df.groupby('shape').count()

```
                      imageName  color1  color2  color3  color4
shape                                                       
cirle                  3         3       3       3       3
square                 1         1       1       1       1
```

EDIT EDIT: I'm looking to get an eventual output to something like this:

```
 Circle: Red     5
         Blue    6
         Green   1
Square:  Yellow  1
         Blue    1
         Red     1
         White   1
```

Comment: What should the output be for your example?

Comment: I added it to the main post

Comment: You've added the output of a command you indicate doesn't work, haven't you? If I'm understanding you correctly, what you'd like is, for each column, the number of times "Red" appears, but only if the shape column for that row also reads 'circle'. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to turn the frame and then `size`:

```
>>> melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["imageName", "shape"], value_name="color")
>>> melted.groupby(["shape","color"]).size()
shape   color 
circle  Blue      6
        Green     1
        Red       5
square  Blue      1
        Red       1
        White     1
        Yellow    1
dtype: int64
```

If you want a frame out instead of a series, that's easy enough too:

```
>>> melted.groupby(["shape","color"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
    shape   color  count
0  circle    Blue      6
1  circle   Green      1
2  circle     Red      5
3  square    Blue      1
4  square     Red      1
5  square   White      1
6  square  Yellow      1
```

Comment: Thank you! I had never used melt before, but it worked perfectly!

Comment: Also, quick follow up question. How would I go about dividing each of those values by the total? Like say there are the 7 blues total. I'd want circle blue to show like 86% and then square blue would be 14%. I have the totals, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into your solution

Comment: @Johnsonge: SO works in a question/answer format, not a threaded one, so followup questions are strongly discouraged.  That said, something like `sizes = melted.groupby(["shape","color"]).size(); sizes/sizes.groupby(level="color").sum()` should work.  PS: I note you haven't yet accepted answers for any of your questions, so you might want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll keep this in mind for future posts

Answer (score 2):

My take using `melt` and `pivot_table`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'color1': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Yellow', 3: 'Blue'}, 'color2': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Green', 2: 'Blue', 3: 'Blue'}, 'color3': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Red', 2: 'Red', 3: 'Blue'}, 'color4': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'White', 3: 'Blue'}, 'shape': {0: 'circle', 1: 'circle', 2: ' square', 3: 'circle'}, 'imageName': {0: 'img1', 1: 'img2', 2: 'img3', 3: 'img4'}})
df = df[['shape','color1','color2','color3','color4']]
cheese = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['shape'], value_vars=['color1','color2','color3','color4'])
pvt = pd.pivot_table(cheese, index=['shape', 'value'], aggfunc=len)

print pvt
```

Result:

```
                variable
shape   value           
 square Blue           1
        Red            1
        White          1
        Yellow         1
circle  Blue           6
        Green          1
        Red            5
```

This is `cheese` prior to being pivoted.

```
      shape variable   value
0    circle   color1     Red
1    circle   color1    Blue
2    square   color1  Yellow
3    circle   color1    Blue
4    circle   color2     Red
5    circle   color2   Green
6    square   color2    Blue
7    circle   color2    Blue
8    circle   color3     Red
9    circle   color3     Red
10   square   color3     Red
11   circle   color3    Blue
12   circle   color4     Red
13   circle   color4    Blue
14   square   color4   White
15   circle   color4    Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'imageName':['img1','img2','img3','img4'],                       
                'color1':['Red','Blue','Yellow','Blue'],
                'color2':['Red','Green','Blue','Blue'],
                'color3':['Red','Red','Red','Blue'],
                'color4':['Red','Blue','White','Blue'],
                'shape':['circle','circle','square','circle']})

df.set_index('imageName',inplace=True)

test = df.set_index('shape').stack()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(test.values,test.index.droplevel(1))
df1.columns = ['Color']
df1['value'] = 1
df1.groupby([df1.index,'Color']).sum()
```

Output:

```
               value
shape  Color        
circle Blue        6
       Green       1
       Red         5
square Blue        1
       Red         1
       White       1
       Yellow      1
```

Comment: img4 doesn't qualify, it's all blue.

Comment: When I do it that way, I run into issues with counting if I count by trues, because the colors and the shape are marked true. Is there a way around this? I also put up a sample in the original post of what I'm shooting for the end goal to look like